# Bash shell script output alignment

Tags: shell-script, scripting, columns, text-formatting

My script:

```
date
echo -e "${YELLOW}Network check${NC}\n\n"

while read hostname
do

ping -c 1 "$hostname" > /dev/null 2>&1 &&

echo -e "Network $hostname : ${GREEN}Online${NC}" ||
echo -e "${GRAY}Network $hostname${NC} : ${RED}Offline${NC}"

done < list.txt
        sleep 30
clear
done
```

Is outputting info like this:

```
Network 10.x.xx.xxx : Online   
Network 10.x.xx.xxx : Offline   
Network 10.x.xx.xxx : Offline   
Network 10.x.xx.xxx : Offline   
Network 10.x.xx.x : Online   
Network 139.xxx.x.x : Online   
Network 208.xx.xxx.xxx : Online   
Network 193.xxx.xxx.x : Online
```

which I'd like to clean up to get something like this:

```
Network 10.x.xx.xxx       : Online  
Network 10.x.xx.xxx       : Offline   
Network 10.x.xx.xxx       : Offline    
Network 10.x.xx.x         : Online    
Network 139.xxx.x.x       : Online  
Network 208.xx.xxx.xxx    : Online    
Network 193.xxx.xxx.x     : Online  
Network 193.xxx.xxx.xxx   : Offline
```

Answer (score 65):

Use `printf` to format output (it's also [more portable than `echo`](/q/65803)). I would also store the real value of the colour escape sequences instead of storing them in a form that requires expansion by `echo`.

```
RED=$(tput setaf 1) GREEN=$(tput setaf 2) YELLOW=$(tput setaf 3)
NC=$(tput sgr0) 
online="${GREEN}online$NC" offline="${RED}offline$NC"

ping -c 1 "$hostname" > /dev/null 2>&1 && state=$online || state=$offline
printf 'Network %-15s: %s\n' "$hostname" "$state"
```

`%-15s` is a format specification that pads the strings with spaces on the right so as the length (in number of characters in `zsh` and `fish` and [bytes in most other shells/printf](/a/350243)) to be at least 15.

```
$ printf '|%-4s|\n' a ab abc abcd abcde
|a   |
|ab  |
|abc |
|abcd|
|abcde|
 printf '|%4s|\n' a ab abc abcd abcde
|   a|
|  ab|
| abc|
|abcd|
|abcde|
```

With truncation:

```
$ printf '|%.4s|\n' a ab abc abcd abcde
|a|
|ab|
|abc|
|abcd|
|abcd|
$ printf '|%4.4s|\n' a ab abc abcd abcde
|   a|
|  ab|
| abc|
|abcd|
|abcd|
$ printf '|%-4.4s|\n' a ab abc abcd abcde
|a   |
|ab  |
|abc |
|abcd|
|abcd|
```

Other utilities to format text in columns include [POSIX `expand`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expand.html):

```
printf 'Network %s\t: %s\n' "$hostname" "$state" | expand -t 30
```

(here expanding the TAB character (`\t`) with tab stops every 30 columns)

Or [BSD `column`](/a/396224) or [POSIX `pr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pr.html):

```
printf 'Network %s\n: %s\n' "$hostname" "$state" | pr -at2
```

(here outputting on 2 36-column wide columns (see the `-w` option to change the page width from the default of 72)).

or [BSD `rs`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rs):

```
{
   while...
      printf 'Network %s\n: %s\n' "$hostname" "$state"
   done
} | rs -e 0 2
```

(like `column` won't start outputting until it has read all the input).

Or [GNU `columns`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autogen/manual/html_section/columns-Invocation.html):

```
printf 'Network %s\n: %s\n' "$hostname" "$state" | columns -w 25 -c 2
```

`zsh` also has some parameter expansion flags for string padding: `${(l[15])hostname}` for *left* padding and `${(r[15])hostname}` for *right* padding (with truncation). With the `m` flag added, that padding takes into account the display width of characters while without all characters are assumed to have the same display width.

In *prompt expansion* (like in prompts or in `print -P` or as enabled in parameter expansions with the `%` flag), it also supports `%F{green}` for colour output, so you can do:

```
online='%F{green}online%f'
printf '%s\n' "Network ${(r[15])hostname}: ${(%)online}"
```

Or:

```
print -rP "Network ${(r[15])hostname}: $online"
```

Though the content of `$hostname` would then also be subject to prompt expansion,
which would constitute a command injection vulnerability if the `promptsubst` option was enabled and the contents of `$hostname` was not under your control (like in `hostname='$(reboot)'`)

Answer (score 58):

Simply with **`column`** command:

```
yourscript.sh | column -t
```

The output:

```
Network  10.x.xx.xxx     :  Online
Network  10.x.xx.xxx     :  Offline
Network  10.x.xx.xxx     :  Offline
Network  10.x.xx.xxx     :  Offline
Network  10.x.xx.x       :  Online
Network  139.xxx.x.x     :  Online
Network  208.xx.xxx.xxx  :  Online
Network  193.xxx.xxx.x   :  Online
```

Comment: im sorry for stupid question, but where i should put that command?

Comment: @pijaaa, see my update, pipe with your script output

Comment: Note that `column` (a BSD command, also ported to Linux and found by default on some distributions, not to  be confused with GNU `columns`) will need to read the whole input before it can start outputting something as it needs to compute the width of the columns based on the widest one.

Answer (score 4):

Update your script to insert a set number to `\t` (tabs) where you want to tab out to a column.

Output something simular to the following would give you the required alignment:

```
Network 10.x.xx.xxx\t: Online   
Network 10.x.xx.xxx\t: Offline   
Network 10.x.xx.xxx\t: Offline   
Network 10.x.xx.xxx\t: Offline   
Network 10.x.xx.x\t: Online   
Network 139.xxx.x.x\t: Online   
Network 208.xx.xxx.xxx\t: Online   
Network 193.xxx.xxx.x\t: Online
```

Comment: It would be worth adding a short example based on the script in the question...

Comment: @StephenKitt ty Stephen, I was trying to figure out how to make it more than just one line, and this honestly didn't occur to me!

Comment: You'll notice that with the default tabstops every 8 columns, `printf 'Network %s\t: Online\n' 8.8.8.8 192.168.122.123` doesn't align properly. You could work around that by using `expand` to expand the tabs with a different tab stop as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

To display even better than @Roman

```
yourscript.sh | column -t -s $'\t'
```

Then add `\t` in each line to split it into column.